# Create Hybridworker in Azure using powershell errors out

Tags: azure, powershell, automation

I am using the code below to create Hybrid worker in a secondary (DR) resource group and add it to an hybridworker group in an automation account in the primary resource group however it fails with the error

```
   $rgDRname = 'rgjt4061rbdr'
   $rgname = 'rgjt4061rb'
   $aaname = 'aajt4061rb'
   $hybridWorkerGroupName = 'hwrvmjt4061rbDNS1'


   # Get the Hybrid Worker Group
   $hybridWorkerGroup = Get-AzAutomationHybridWorkerGroup -ResourceGroupName $rgname -          AutomationAccountName $aaname -Name $hybridWorkerGroupName


   $vmDNS1resource = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgDRname | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "vm*DNS1" }
   [string]$vmDNS1resourceid = $vmDNS1resource.Id

   # Create a new Hybrid Worker configuration
   $hybridWorkerConfiguration = @{
       ResourceGroupName = $rgname
       AutomationAccountName = $aaname
       VmResourceId = $vmDNS1resourceid 
       HybridRunbookWorkerGroupName = $hybridWorkerGroupName
       Name = $vmDNS1resource.Name
   }

   # Add the new Hybrid Worker to the group
   New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker @hybridWorkerConfiguration
```

I got the error below

```
This is the error i have New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker : The hybrid runbook worker id &#39;vmjt4061rbDNS1&#39; is not in proper GUID format.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker @hybridWorkerConfiguration | gm
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker], ErrorResponseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Automation.Cmdlet.NewAzureAutomationHybridRunbookWorker
```

Powershell Command but fails ..

If there is a way I can use Microsoft graph instead. that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the GUID value for `-Name` property as mentioned in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/extension-based-hybrid-runbook-worker-install?tabs=windows%2Carm-template#manage-hybrid-worker-extension-using-bicep--arm-templates-rest-api-azure-cli-and-powershell) on how to create and manage the hybrid worker.

I have modified the above shared PowerShell script and using the below I am able to deploy the Hybrid Runbook worker without any issues.

```
 $rgDRname = 'rgjt4061rbdr'
   $rgname = 'rgjt4061rb'
   $aaname = 'aajt4061rb'
   $hybridWorkerGroupName = 'hwrvmjt4061rbDNS1'
   $workerName= New-Guid


   $vmDNS1resource = Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName $rgDRname | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "vm*DNS1" }
   $vmDNS1resourceid = $vmDNS1resource.Id

   # Create a new Hybrid Worker configuration
   $hybridWorkerConfiguration = @{
       ResourceGroupName = $rgname
       AutomationAccountName = $aaname
       VmResourceId = $vmDNS1resourceid 
       HybridRunbookWorkerGroupName = $hybridWorkerGroupName
       Name = $workerName
   }

   # Add the new Hybrid Worker to the group
   New-AzAutomationHybridRunbookWorker @hybridWorkerConfiguration
```